# Ubuntu 12.04 : Should I update?

Tags: 12.04, server, upgrade

I have a server with Ubuntu Server 12.04 installed. It is a Pentium M old computer (about 2006), with a very basic BIOS.

I am having some problems with the server, namely, running the latest versions of well-known programs...

Then, should I update it to a newer version of Ubuntu? Which one is the highest version supported by my system? Is it in fact the one that I got?

Comment: 18.04 is the latest and last version for 32bit computers.  Using 12.04 your best bet is for a clean install, instead of an upgrade.  Ubuntu not supporting 32bit with this year's version 20.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your machine is off-line without connection to the web, then you'll be safe using an *unsupported*, *un-patched* system like Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (which has been EOL since April 2019)

If your machine is serving other machines that are connected to the web, the risk will be increased over the safety of all machines being off-line, and upgrading is for sure recommended.

Personally I used model M and model 4 processors to test *flavors* up to and including 19.04 cycle (Lubuntu & Xubuntu) or until the x86/i386 images were dropped (pre-release), however with 18.10 & 19.04 now EOL they should likewise be avoided.

The last release I tested was *flavors* of Ubuntu 18.04.5 (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/) and it's what I'd recommend.

If you're using Ubuntu 18.04.5 server, it will be supported 5 years from release (2018-April) or 2023-April (http://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/) and it's what I'd select.

I did have some issues with the (18.04.5 5.4; others did too) HWE kernel on 2003 pentium M models, thus I'd recommend using 18.04 LTS with the GA kernel, but none of those issues were noticed on pentium M processors used in 2005 model laptops. Myself (and I use 2x pentium M laptops) I use the GA kernel.

The upgrade path from 12.04 LTS was to 12.10 (next release) or next LTS release (14.04 which is now EOL & ESM only), so you've missed the intended upgrade path. You could try, but personally given it's out of support (14.04 being EOL & ESM only is off-topic on this and other Ubuntu sites now), I'd recommend re-install of Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (no desktop in i386, I've assumed *flavor* or server; if you're using a server I'd recommend a light *flavor* for sure)

Comment: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1892011   https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1891790

Comment: Re: If wondering why bugs are dated after release; I tested on those devices only after support problems appeared here & on https://discourse.lubuntu.me/ . In the 18.04.4 cycle I tested using more model m laptops; in 18.04.5 I opted for what was easy (and skipped the older thinkpads). 18.04.4 HWE kernel had no issues with any, only pentium Ms needing `forcepae` to install had issues this time & it was these I skipped testing pre-release. These devices are 100% stable using 18.04's GA kernel though (I'd not recommend the older 5.3 HWE kernel though as it's EOL)